# Android wifi hotspot client connection events

Tags: android, wifi, portability, tethering

I am connecting different devices with wifi hotspot AP programatically in my android app, How can i detect the clients being connected and disconnected and to the wifi hotspot AP i turned on programmatically ? Is there any callback event in Android API to give information regarding the connection or disconnection events of individual devices ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have same SSID everywhere? in that case you can check for that SSID is connected or not

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use `WifiP2pDevice`
There you can check for available devices, and also if they are connected or not.

Try looking here at the available methods [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pDevice.html)

***EDIT***:

This [Android Wifi Hotspot Manager Class](http://www.whitebyte.info/android/android-wifi-hotspot-manager-class) have sample code to scan `/proc/net/arp` and ping each known client to detect livelihood.

You can implement that logic in a loop to **emulate** a Wifi Client disconnect event from driver.

Comment: Sorry but the question is not related to `WifiP2p`.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood.

Comment: BTW, someone asked the same question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522961/how-to-get-the-client-device-details-which-is-connected-to-wifi-hotspot

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378143/callback-on-device-connecting-to-wifi-hotspot?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I've read that code. It reads `/proc/net/arp` and ping each known client to detect livelihood. I'll edit your answer and award you the bounty.