# How to get Wi-Fi hotspot clients connectivity status in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-wifi, wifimanager

I have created a WI-FI Hotspot in my app and then I try to show a toast message when a device connects to my hotspot.

I have tried this :

```
private var onClientConnected = object : BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
         Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Client Connected!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

and register it using this:

```
registerReceiver(onClientConnected, IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.WIFI_HOTSPOT_CLIENTS_CHANGED"))
```

But at run time when a device connects to hotspot. I get no Toast message.
Is there anything that I have missed or doing wrong?

Comment: Don't think there is a built in method to determine the number of devices connected to your hotspot. However, this might be helpful - [Android Wifi Hotspot Manager](https://github.com/nickrussler/Android-Wifi-Hotspot-Manager-Class), let me know if that helps

Comment: @Nero Thanks, But I don't want to get numbers of connected device. I want to show a toast msg when a device connects to hotspot.

Comment: but you might be able to use that around your logic? It might not be a future proof answer but you can run the method every 10 seconds or so to determine if the number of connected devices has increased. If it has, that means a new device has been connected. I am still searching for correct answer which is more robust.

Comment: @Nero Thank for your help, but my project is in kotlin and the link you shared is in java.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. Check permissions and try to expose the BroadcastReceiver inside the manifest (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33983335/603270)